# Adding Badges to Trello

Tags: trello

The Trello on Trello and Trello Dev boards have a custom Badge for Fogbugz.  Are there additional badges or is there a way to add Custom Badges?

Comment: There isn't a way to add custom badges to Trello yet. (I'm a part of the Trello team).

Answer (score 0):

You can suggest it on the [Trello Development Board](https://trello.com/b/verymeta) for consideration, if it's not already there.